# how to add image into the jframe by coding in java swings in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created the a frame Layout that implements action Listener . here i am 
     creating the frames and menu items  only by coding. and I am trying to put image 
     this frame, so please help me how to add image to the frame in java swings in 
     net beans

Comment: I'm curious, did you even search before asking here?

Comment: Best comments ever. Short, simple, sincere and yet so powerful...

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can see below link:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-image-display.html

I hope it resolves your query